# Google Alert API for PHP

Tags: php, google-alerts

Is there any free Google alert Api out there ? I am trying to build the php application with google alert. But it seems that there is no such api

Comment: http://oktaykilic.com/programming/google-alerts-api-class/

Answer (score 1):

The sites that spryno724 is providing don't allow you to download the library, I also tried to contact the authors without response.

Finally after searching a lot I found a recent and working php lib here:

http://coders11.com/googlealertsapi

**Last update: 11/02/2014 :** 
For various reasons this class is not free anymore.
You can buy a full commercial license for €60 / $67

Comment: That linked library at coder11 has reduced the price to €16. I bought it and it worked great apart from a doublequote escape bug. I sent the fix to the author.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, what have you tried? You will probably get that question alot on here if you don't show that you have researched this first.

There doesn't appear to be any offical Google Alert APIs, but here are some third-party ones for PHP:

- http://nicholasdejong.com/story/api-google-alerts
- http://oktaykilic.com/programming/google-alerts-api-class/ (mentioned in answer of duplicate question)

Comment: As of today, those are both dead links.